# Vagrant up error with windows 10

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, windows-10, vagrantfile

After upgrading to windows 10 I have been having trouble getting my vagrant box to work. I tried following the steps at this link [fix vagrant issue with windows 10](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=67675) but still could not get it to work. The steps were also not documented very well so I could have done something wrong. Does someone have a work around to fix this issue?

$vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

==> default: Importing base box 'TLWPLGZN'...

==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...

==> default: Setting the name of the VM: UMUWXLAR

==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...

Progress state: E_FAIL

VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter

VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_FAIL (0x80004005) - Unspecified error (extended info not available)

VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "int __cdecl handleCreate(struct HandlerArg *,int,int *)" at line 66 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virual Box has released a patch that when ran while loading your virtual machine allows virtualbox to correctly establish its network adapter in windows 10